# The application does not contain a valid bundle identifier.

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I know this question has been asked before, but I have tried the given solutions, and none have worked. I am switching development computers, and starting a brand new project on my new computer. We already have a certificate that we used on the old computer, so I exported the Developer Certificate from my old computer, and installed it in my new machine. I created and downloaded a provisioning profile for my new application on the new computer. I am trying to run the application on a test device, whose UDID I added to the provisioning profile, so it would be valid for this device.

The provisioning profile was created with the apple ID I created online with the the form com.mycompany.projectname.

When I try to run the application on the test device(it does not work on the simulator either), I get an error popup that says **The application does not contain a valid bundle identifier.**

My bundle identifier, which I checked both the Targets -> Summary -> Identifier and the Info.plist is showing correctly in the form of com.mycompany.projectname, with neither the company name, nor the project name having any special characters in it.

Am I missing something? I have been beating my head against the wall with this for a while now...

Comment: The Simulator doesn't have signed code, so I don't think it'll be a provisioning profile issue. How about looking at the plist in the .app bundle?

Comment: @DavidDunham I need to run it on an actual device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember the last time this happened to us was when we noobishly trashed our app's plist.  Luckily, we had an older copy on the old time capsule, and restored it.  But we had changed the bundle ID since and it kept showing us that error.  Matching the cert with the Bundle ID is critical.  Make ABSOLUTELY sure the names on the cert match the bundle ID, or check the organizer to see if the cert even installed in the first place.  If need be, as an absolute last resort, change the bundle ID and get a new cert.

Comment: The identifiers are the same an the provisioning profile and in the plist. I just tried using a new id in the plist and created a new provisioning profile with the new id and I got the same error...

Comment: Wait, you said you changed it in the plist right?  What does the line marked "bundle identifier" say?  It should say "com.companyname.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}"

Answer (score 1):

We ensure that “the plist” and “ general->identify->Bundle Identifier ” have a same Bundle Identifier。and the Bundle Identifier's stytle maybe be like "com.mycompany.projectname "

**Follow these steps：**

1. look plist whether have the Bundle Identifier
2. look general->identify->Bundle Identifier whether the same as plist in Xcode
3. if the same  maybe Bundle Identifier  is inAppropriate。 so you can set Bundle Identifier like "com.mycompany.projectname "

Comment: Can you please elaborate or explain your answer?

Comment: the plist and "general->identify->Bundle Identifier" must be same.and,the sytle is "com.mycompany.projectname".

Comment: Alright. I got it now but your answer is in bad format that's why it's kinda confusing to read (for others). I can't edit your answer either so if you can, please do. They are bulleted list but as we can see, they are not in proper format.